How to instruct `auto` to simplify the goal during proof search?
A minimal example of my issue looks as follows:
Goal let x := True in x.

This is immediately solved by simpl. auto., but auto. does not work.
In my actual case, the search tree is a bit bigger than that. It involves many intermediate steps in which auto would be able to proceed, but it bails out scared off by some zeta-reducible let expressions. Even if I wanted to, I can't even make it stop there and let me manually insert that simpl (because auto either solves or leaves the goal unchanged).
What is the proper way of dealing with that? If possible, I want to avoid adding an Extern Hint simpl to brutally apply simpl on every let everywhere in my program. I don't need to stick to auto; any other tactic which would do the job in a non-superfluous way is fine by me.

Are any of: now auto. intuition. firstorder. suitable in your case?

now auto works only if I the simpl is needed only at the almost-leaves of the search tree. In my case I need auto to keep working after simplification. intuition does not work, and as far as I can see it does not let me specify my hint databases or use existential automation. firstorder I am not sure what does in general, but in my case it's nothing (even if I fuel it with eauto with mydb).

if you have some database db and you want to use existential stuff then you should be able to do intuition eauto with db. Otherwise, perhaps you could post a slightly less minimal example that actually illustrates the failure with these alternatives?

You can tell auto to try arbitrary tactics with Hint extern.
E.g.
Hint Extern 5 => progress simpl : core.

would work. But this is dangerous and might lead to slow auto. The number (5) is a cost - auto will first try all hints with lower cost. The progress ensures that the hint does not apply in case it doesn't change anything, so that simpl won't loop.

It's something I considered, but my intuition is that if it is not there by default, there might be good reasons for that.

It is definitely not a good idea to add it to the core databases, but it does make sense to add it to a separate hint database and instruct auto to use this (in addition of core). You can also add a hint locally, to that it is not exported. If it works for your proofs, it is fine.

Okay, with that comment it sounds like the solution
